# Solr highlights error

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using solr 4.6 with Jetty and as a client latest solrnet build (1672). I haven't done any changes to solrconfig.xml or schema.xml, because all I need is content and id of the document. My class is:

```
public class Register
{
    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [SolrField("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [SolrField("text")]
    public string Text{get;set;}
}
```

I insert documents into solr with code:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                var response =
                    Solr.Extract(
                        new ExtractParameters(fileStream, txtId.Text)
                        {                            
                            ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
                            ExtractOnly = false,

                        });            

                            }

            Solr.Commit();
```

My problem is that I can't make highlights to work. My code for highlightning:

```
QueryOptions options = 
new QueryOptions{Highlight = new HighlightingParameters{Fields = new[] {"id", "content", "text"}}};
                SolrQueryByField query = new SolrQueryByField("text", "nhibernate");
                var res = Solr.Query(query, options);
```

When the third line is executed I am receiving an error:

{"Could not convert value 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to property 'Content' of document type SolrTest.Register"}

What could be wrong here? I have followed [this link](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Highlighting.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that in the default schema.xml file, the field `content` is defined with `multiValued=true`. Telling Solr to allow multiple values for this field within a single document, e.g. stored as an array. So you need to change the Content property in your Register class to the following:

```
 [SolrField("content")]
 public ICollection<string> Content { get; set; }
```

As shown in the [SolrNet Mapping documentation](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Mapping.md).

Comment: Since content field is not copyied anywhere, I don't know why it's mapped with multiValue attribute? I've changed this in schema.xml, just removed multiValued and it was cool. But, I agree with your answer, too. One thing is not clear to me yet: I've got six highlights from my query. Key value for each highlight is there, but  value is empty. And value should be in fact snippet of text?

Comment: It might be the case that there are not any matches within your specified fields for highlighting. Since you are querying against the text field (which is a copyField destination from various other fields) other fields could be driving the query and not displaying in highlights. You can specify "*" as the highlight field to see if you get any results. Also checkout the Highlighting parameters http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters as there are lots of options to consider. Also I would recommend testing against Solr directly initially to ensure you are getting the expected results.